# Firebase query with wrong data doesn't give any call back

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a table in firebase and saved couple of data and want to query specific data by specifying inputs like where condition in Sqlite :

```
Query queryRef = ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo(username); 

queryRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChild) { 
       // i get the call back if i specify username which is already there in table 
    } 
});
```

my problem is when i pass any value which doesn't exist in table then i don't get any call back.

how to handle such scenario in Firebase. is there any other call back which i should be listening to ?

Comment: Hey @Atmaram, let me know if my answer was not clear or you still have any other concern. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `addChildEventListener` listener with addListenerForSingleValueEvent for single value you get call back defiantly like following ,

```
 Query queryRef = ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo(username);
        queryRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //if match your data otherwise return null
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: onDataChange is called but dataSnapshot is always having null value

Comment: you are doing some thing wrong because I have test recently its working fine,

Comment: Or more one another thing string completely match with data then it return other wise it return null,

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `addValueEventListener()`. You can find more details on this [other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35521884/how-to-know-if-firebase-childeventlistener-found-child-android).

But your code will look like the following and you will be able to see if there is some matching results using `snapshot.exists()`.

```
 Query queryRef = ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo(username); 

 queryRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

     @Override
     public void onDataChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
       if (snapshot.exists()) {
         //found results
       }
       else {
         //not found
       }
     }

  });
```

Comment: With any input its  returning false to snapshot.exists()

Comment: @Atmaram Have you tryied addin the onCancelled and debugging the callback from there? Does it show any error?