# I want to get the data from a firebase object how?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Okay, am using firebase I tried some code from the docs that show me how to retrieve data from my DB. Am using the Web Docs Okay
Here is what my DB looks like

```
 MyApp-446464
 users
    foo
     -foobar
       first_name:"foo"
       last_name:"bar"

    bar
     -barfoo
       first_name:"bar"
       last_name:"foo"
```

So from the above, I get the object using

```
firebase.database().ref('users/').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
   var username = snapshot.val();
});
```

But the problem is I can't seem to get the value if I use

```
username.first_name;
```

its giving me undefined can someone assist me with what am doing wrong

Comment: why do you have you user info under two level childs? `/users/id1/id2`

Comment: The first one is the uid and the other created from a push @adolfosrs

Answer (score 8):

Your code is asking for the entire list of users. So it must handle that list in the callback:

```
firebase.database().ref('users/').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
        var username = userSnapshot.val();
        console.log(username.first_name);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey Frank, I'm sure this works but shouldn't we encourage users to not design this kind of structure? I mean, this extra id is totally unnecessary and adding complexity. Thanks and regards.

Comment: This should be mark as the correct answers you saw what I was fully accomplishing but I did use @adolfosrs to shape the DB different instead of using push and the uid I set the uid as a child but thanks to both you guys Frank and adolfosrs okay

Comment: @adolfosrs: if you need all users, my snippet is a valid approach. You might want to use `child_` events, but the only difference is that they make it easier to update the UI (which often is a pretty good reason to use them). If you need only a single user, then you should indeed not retrieve a list but preferably access the user directly by their `uid` or (secondary) through a query.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yeah, agreed. My point is that this would get unscalable. With a high number of users you might spend a considerable time to retrieve them. With some refactoring we can leave this complexetity to the server side.

Answer (score 2):

This wont be possible having `/users/uid/id2`.

Make sure you save your user data using `ref.child('users').child(uid).set(userDataObject)`.

Then you will be able to retrieve the data using `orderByChild` and `equalTo`. You can use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37812136/firebase-query-with-wrong-data-doesnt-give-any-call-back) as reference to achieve it.

```
var ref =  firebase.database().ref();
ref.child('users').orderByChild('first_name').equalTo(username.first_name).once('value' ...
```

Comment: can I ask you won't set rewrite the data? @adolfosrs

Comment: @Redcode Yes it is. But using this approach you can set only a expecific field if you want. `ref.child('users').child(uid).child('first_name').set('Redcode')`

Comment: @Redcode Nice! let me know if you still have any doubts. And keep asking :)

Comment: Thanks you make me feel more welcome :) u just motivate me@adolfosrs