# Start next activity if firebase database has no child value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am  using to populate the Recycleview Adapter form firebase database in Activity A. I am looking for solution to return to Mainactivity when it has empty parent or no child.

Here is my code

```html
public class SubjectBooks extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseAuth fauth;
    String user;
    DatabaseReference dbreference,dbref;
    RecyclerView rv;
    String subject;
    int child_count=0;
    ArrayList<Books> list;
    SubjectBooksAdapter staggeredBooksAdapter;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subject_books);
       


        fauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        subject = getIntent().getStringExtra("subject").trim();

        dbreference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("books").child(subject);
        dbreference.keepSynced(true);
        user = fauth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();

      

        final ProgressDialog  progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading...", "Please wait...", true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        progressDialog.show();

       
        dbreference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                final Books b1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Books.class);
              //  Log.e("Value is ",dataSnapshot.getKey()+" "+b1.getBauthor());
                //Log.e("Book"," received");
                if(!user.equals(b1.getSelleremail()) || (user.equals(b1.getSelleremail())) ) {

                    child_count++;
                    list.add(b1);
                    staggeredBooksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                


             
              if(child_count==0){
                   progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(SubjectBooks.this, "No books found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   Intent in = new Intent(SubjectBooks.this,MainActivity.class);
                   startActivity(in);
                    finish();
               }
            }
```

I have initially declared

```
int child_count=0;
```

But also when it has no any child value..still progressDialog keeps loading infinitely unless any key is pressed.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `onChildAdded()` will only be called when a new child has been added or a child already exist.

In your case, you don't have any child added, So `onChildAdded()` is never been called. that's why **progressDialog keeps loading infinitely**

To detect if a child exists, use `ValueEventListener` instead of `ChildEventListener`. Here is link [how to use `ValueEventListener`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35521884/how-to-know-if-firebase-childeventlistener-found-child-android)

Answer (score 1):

You can use exists to check if the path that refers your database reference exists

```
 dbreference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                if(!dataSnapshot.exists()){

                final Books b1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Books.class);
              //  Log.e("Value is ",dataSnapshot.getKey()+" "+b1.getBauthor());
                //Log.e("Book"," received");
                if(!user.equals(b1.getSelleremail()) || (user.equals(b1.getSelleremail())) ) {

                    child_count++;
                    list.add(b1);
                    staggeredBooksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }




           }else{
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(SubjectBooks.this, "No books found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent in = new Intent(SubjectBooks.this,MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    finish();

            }
}
```

### **exists**

exists() returns boolean

> Returns true if this DataSnapshot contains any data. It is slightly
>   more efficient than using snapshot.val() !== null.

That will check if there is data inside the path your `dbReference` points out, but it will not check if the childs inside are > 0.

To do so you can check after the else statment if inside that node you have more than 1 child node

```
   ...
            }else{

                 long childrenQty = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();;
                  if(childrenQty > 0 ) {
                   //We have >= than 1 children to show in our recyclerView  :-)
                  }else{
                   //Theres nothing inside to show in our recyclerView  :-(
                               progressDialog.dismiss();
                               Toast.makeText(SubjectBooks.this, "No books found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                               Intent in = new Intent(SubjectBooks.this,MainActivity.class);
                               startActivity(in);
                               finish();

                        }
}
```

Comment: just one thing....is it not enough to use your uppersolution with if(!dataSnapshot.exists()). what is use of the down solution....I should use both or the below is an option for other use?

Comment: do both, because if your reference someday refers to a null reference in your Firebase structure it will crash your app, adding the first solution will prevent that, and with both will work as you expect

Comment: nope it didn't work still progressDialog rotates indifinitely

Comment: you should also check with yourAdapter.getItemCount() before set the adapter

Comment: I appreciate your help but Ali method worked for me..Thanks for help anyway.